Not able to store in the localStorage using the chrome extension
I am trying to create a Chrome extension that bookmarks the parts of the YouTube video and stores the timestamp of the YouTube video in the localStorage. Below is the code I tried the following code, and I can see the array with all the timestamps but as soon as I refresh the page, the data is getting erased.
This is for checking if there are any timestamps for that video
// add listener to the message from the background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  const { message, url } = request;
  if (message === "newVideo") {
    currentVideoURL = url.split("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")[1];
  }

  // checking the local storage for the bookmarks
  chrome.storage.local.get([currentVideoURL]).then((result) => {
    if (result[currentVideoURL]) {
      bookmarksArray = JSON.parse(result[currentVideoURL]);
    } else {
      bookmarksArray = [];
    }
  });
  console.log(bookmarksArray);
// this function only creates the icon element to display on the youtube player
createBookmarkBtn(); 
});

Below is the convertTime function that converts the time according to the time shown on youtube player and also stores the timestamp of the video in the localStorage
function convertTime(seconds) {
  let hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  let minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
  let remainingSeconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
  let formattedHours = hours.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedMinutes = minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedSeconds = remainingSeconds.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedTime = `${formattedHours}:${formattedMinutes}:${formattedSeconds}`;

  const newBookmark = {
    time: formattedTime,
    desc: "Bookmark at " + formattedTime,
  };
  if (bookmarksArray.length === 0) {
    bookmarksArray = [newBookmark];
  } else {
    bookmarksArray.unshift(newBookmark);
    chrome.storage.local
      .set({ currentVideoURL: JSON.stringify(bookmarksArray) })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Data saved");
      });
  }

  return formattedTime;
}


Move console.log and createBookmarkBtn() inside the callback of chrome.storage.loca.get. Don't forget to reload the extension in chrome://extensions page afterwards.

There's probably another mistake in convertTime because it sets the storage asynchronously, but I can't say without seeing the code that calls convertTime.
